# TypeError in CSV clean-up Script

Tags: python, csv

I'm having trouble designing a script that will delete designated rows and columns from a CSV file. Here's my script so far:

```
import csv
with open ("E:\\CSULB Grad\\2016 Spring\\Geog 588\\Project\\ACS_14_5YR_B02001_Copy.csv","rb") as csvfile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
with open ("E:\\CSULB Grad\\2016 Spring\\Geog 588\\Project\\ACS_14_5YR_B02001_Copy.csv","ab+") as csvfile2:
    writer=csv.writer(csvfile2)
    for row in csvfile2:
        del row['HD02_VD01']
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Here's the traceback error I've been getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
File "E:\CSULB Grad\2016 Spring\Geog 588\Project\Script2.py", line 7, in <module>
    del row['HD02_VD01']
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item deletion
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify a CSV file in-place as you iterate over it. Consider creating a new CSV file that writes only the columns that you require for each row in the original file.

For instance:

```
    with open(path,"wb") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = fieldNames)
        for row in csvfile2:
            writer.writerow({"Col1":row['...'],"Col2":row['...']})
```

Comment: Can you tell me what you mean in by d1 in ({"Col1":d1,"Col2":d2}) ? My course didn't teach us how to operate with dictionaries, which is what it looks like we're supposed to be doing here.

The code I tried ends up being


    import csv
    with open ("E:\\CSULB Grad\\2016 Spring\\Geog 588\\Project\\ACS_14_5YR_B02001_Copy.csv","a") as csvfile:
    writer=csv.DictWriter(csvfile,fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writerow({'GEO.id':'GEOID','GEO.id2':'GEOID_2','GEO.display-label':'CEN_TRACT','HD01_VD01':'POP_TOT'})

Comment: and I get this Traceback

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "E:\CSULB Grad\2016 Spring\Geog 588\Project\Script4.py", line 4, in <module>
    writer.writerow({'GEO.id':'GEOID','GEO.id2':'GEOID_2','GEO.display-label':'CEN_TRACT','HD01_VD01':'POP_TOT'})

ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'GEO.id2', 'GEO.id', 'HD01_VD01', 'GEO.display-label'

Comment: Please see the edited answer. d1/d2 were just arbitrary variable names for data to be set to.

Comment: Thanks.  Now I'm getting another error though. Here's the line of code:  writer.writerow({'Col1':row[0],'Col2':row[1],'Col3':row[2],'Col4':row[3],'Col5':row[17]}).

Comment: Here's the traceback: line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "E:\CSULB Grad\2016 Spring\Geog 588\Project\Script4.py", line 4, in <module>
  writer.writerow({'Col1':row[0],'Col2':row[1],'Col3':row[2],'Col4':row[3],'Col5':row[17]})
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\csv.py", line 152, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'Col4', 'Col5', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col1'

Comment: Fieldnames should be a list of strings that correspond to the column strings you use (e.g. fieldnames = ['Col1', ...])

Comment: My new code just produces this "G E O . O", one per column instead of bringing in the entire column.    Code: import csv
fieldnames = ["GEOID", "GEOID2", "CENSUS_TRACTS", "POP_TOT", "TWO_RACES"]
with open ("E:\\CSULB Grad\\2016 Spring\\Geog 588\\Project\\ACS_14_5YR_B02001_Copy.csv","w") as csvfile:
    writer=csv.DictWriter(csvfile,fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writerow({fieldnames[0]:row[0],fieldnames[1]:row[1],fieldnames[2]:row[2],fieldnames[3]:row[3],fieldnames[4]:row[17]})
print "DONE"